# How to cancel the selected state of the ListItem I have clicked after I click it again?

Tags: java, android, listview

In my app, I have a `listView` whose item is **choice mode** is **singlechoice**. When I click an item, its background color gets dark. When I click it again, it is still with dark background. I want it to come back to the previous background color after I click again.

Now my solution is to use the `myList.setSelector(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))` function every time I click the item.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    myList.setSelector(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.gray_white)));
    if (position==prePosition){
        if(isSelected==UNSELECTED){
            isSelected=SELECTED;
            if (position>lock_listItems.size())
                floatingActionButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else{
            isSelected=UNSELECTED;
            floatingActionButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            myList.setItemChecked(position,false);
            //view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            myList.setSelector(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        }
    }
    else {
        isSelected=SELECTED;
        if (position>lock_listItems.size())
            floatingActionButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        else
            floatingActionButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        prePosition=position;
    }
    myList.forceLayout();
}
```

I think this solution is not so effective. Any better solution?

Comment: You are using a single API call (setSelector), why do you feel that is not effective?

Comment: If it works, it's fine. If you want a better solution I would suggest not using a ListView at all. RecyclerView is much more commonly used, more flexible, more features etc

Comment: @bunbun I just wonder if there is an API maybe called setItemSelected(false) that I can change the inside state of the item rather than just change the backgroundcolor.

Comment: @MikeSpeed Thanks for your advice. I will use RecyclerView next time.

Answer (score 0):

Take an `arraylist`.
First check the clicked position is present in the `arraylist` or not by using 
`Collections.contains(position);`
If it returns true, don't do anything. Otherwise do your stuff. You can do as below:

```
ArrayList<Integer> myPositionClickedList = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // this should be as global variable
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {   
    if(!myPositionClickedList.contains(position)) {
        myList.setSelector(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.gray_white)));

        //do your stuff here........
        myPositionClickedList.add(position);
    }  
}
```

Comment: My purpose is not making multiple choice or multiple select. Just single select. But unselect it after I click it twice. I am looking for some API that google offered which can cancel the selected state swiftly or other more effective manual ways.